# Hydrate timestamp fields to PEAR Date objects

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

In my Symfony/Doctrine application, I would like any timestamp fields in my database to retreived as PEAR `Date` objects instead of date strings. e.g. If my schema is

```
SomeEvent:
   columns:
      id:
         type: integer
         primary: true
      start: timestamp
      end: timestamp
```

I would like to be able to run a Doctrine query to retrieve `SomeEvent` objects and have `$anEvent->getStart()` be a PEAR `Date` object. Right now Doctrine gives me strings for all timestamp fields which is basically useless. (I'd also like saving of Dates to work correctly.)

What's the best way to accomplish this?

I researched using a Hydration listener but it looks like I'd have to register that per table and hardcode the column names that I want to be converted. Using a custom Hydrator didn't look much better since then I lose the ability to use any of the other core hydration methods without having my dates be strings again.

*EDIT:* It looks like Doctrine 2 has a feature that's exactly what I'm looking for: [Custom Mapping Types](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/basic-mapping.html#custom-mapping-types). Unfortunately this site is being deployed to a host that doesn't support PHP 5.3+ so Doctrine 2 is out. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a hacky way to do it that I'm not super happy with, but it works. I created the following 2 classes:

```
class DateClassBehavior extends Doctrine_Template {

   public function setTableDefinition() {
      $listener = new DateClassListener();
      $table = $this->getTable();

      foreach ($table->getColumns() as $columnName => $columnDef) {
         if ($columnDef['type'] == 'timestamp') {
            $listener->dateColumns[] = $columnName;
         }
      }

      $this->addListener($listener);
   }

}

class DateClassListener extends Doctrine_Record_Listener {

   public $dateColumns = array();

   public function postHydrate(Doctrine_Event $event) {
      $data = $event->data;

      foreach ($this->dateColumns as $col) {
         $date = $data->$col == null ? null : new Date($data->$col);
         $data->$col = null;
         $data->$col = $date;
      }

      $event->data = $data;
   }

}
```

And added DateClassBehavior to the definition for each table in my model:

```
SomeEvent:
   actAs: [DateClassBehavior]
   columns:
      id:
         type: integer
         primary: true
      start: timestamp
      end: timestamp
```

This takes care of creating the `Date` objects when things are loaded. I also modified the actual PEAR `Date` class (I know... bad) and added a `__toString()` method that returns `$this->getDate()`. PHP then automatically converts the dates to the correct string when doctrine saves them.

If anyone finds a better way to do this please post it.